# Measure simple, highly repeated operations in Python

Tags: python, performance

I have a large dataset I need to run a few short operations over repeatedly in Python. As the dataset grows, the runtime of the entire process grows quadratically. Obviously, there are ways to batch these operations so that they run faster, but I want to measure which operations are taking the most compute time before I try to optimize them.

However, when I try to measure the runtime of the operations, I am getting inconsistent results. In other words, the sum of the runtimes of each operation is not close to the total runtime. I've constructed a simple example.

```
import time
import tqdm
all_times = {"Mult":0,"Add":0,"Full":0}

s1 = time.process_time()
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(int(1e4))):
    for j in range(i):
        s = time.process_time()
        z = i*i
        all_times["Mult"] += (time.process_time() - s)

        s = time.process_time()
        z = i+i
        all_times["Add"] += (time.process_time() - s)

all_times["Full"] += (time.process_time() - s1)
print(all_times)
```

Resulting in something like `{'Mult': 17.977712000036018, 'Add': 17.74207199997629, 'Full': 69.089015}` where my real-world clock measured time is also ~70 seconds.

The only things not being measured in "Mult" and "Add" are the timing operations themselves, and the incrementation of `i` and `j`. If I remove the inner timing operations, the runtime of the process as a whole is not really affected. Surely, incrementing these iterators cannot be that expensive.

How do I measure these shorter operations more accurately?

Comment: `tqdm` is far from cheap - it does quite a lot of things (like creating a visual representation of how long the iteration has come, which means writing to the terminal etc.), and that's probably what most of your time is spent doing (it's not "just incrementing an iterator"). If you want to evaluate simple operations, use `timeit`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html - "Measure execution time of small code snippets"

Comment: "The only things not being measured in "Mult" and "Add" are the timing operations themselves, and the incrementation of i and j" No. You aren't measuring what each iteration over the `tqdm.tqdm` object is doing, which involves a lot of things like printing to the screen (which usually takes up a lot of time, relatively speaking)

Comment: Also note, iteration is not free, it involves at least a function call. Which is not cheap compared to `i * i` or `i + i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you add code for timing in your code, you're changing what you're observing.

You can use `timeit` https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html to check on timing of a piece of code.

Or to see the execution for each function, you should use `cProfile`

```
python -m cProfile mycode.py
```

You can even save a profile file and then analyze it to generate a FlameGraph
https://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html

To do that, save the profile like:

```py
python -m cProfile -o profile.prof mycode.py
```

then use `flameprof`

https://github.com/baverman/flameprof

```
pip install flameprof
```

Then

```
python flameprof.py profile.prof > output.svg
```

Open the SVG in your browser to see the Flame graph